# JAVA - Converstion String (With dot) to Long

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have problem about convertion from string to long value. Example :

```
String a = "4.0";
Long l= Long.parseLong(a);
```

When I execute, get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4.0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at com.tests.Test2.main(Test2.java:69)
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4.0` isn't a long value It's a double, Try `Double.parseDouble(a)`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to covert a string with an unsupported character, `.`, into a `Long`. This is not supported by https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String). Try `Long l = Double.valueOf(a).longValue();`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Double.valueOf(a)

Double.parseDouble(String) will return a primitive double type. 
Double.valueOf(String) will return a wrapper object of type Double.

Depending on your need you can use one of teh above

Answer (score 0):

Ur code String a = "4.0";
Str a isnt Long,It's Double,
if U want to converstion to Long, U need to converstion Double.type first.
U should :
  Double d = Double.valueOf(a);
  then 
  Long re = d.longValue() or use Ur method Long re = d.toLong
 re is final result.

Comment: Mostly sounds correct, except "use Ur method Long re = d.toLong". What is `d.toLong`? I can't find `Double#toLong` in the `Double` JDK Javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

```
!a.contains(".") ? Long.parseLong(a) : (long) Double.parseDouble(a)
```